# WPF color theme using 3 levels for color properties

Tags: c#, wpf

In our WPF application, we're looking to implement a color management system with three levels of color properties:

1. **Primitive** (Static Colors)

We have a set of static color definitions, such as:

- color/darkblue-800: #3D4B66
- color/white: #FFFFFF
- ...

2. **Semantic** (Light and Dark Variants)

The Semantic level includes two variants: Light and Dark. For instance:

Dark Variant:

- colors/background/bg-primary: primitive/color/darkblue-800
- ...

Light Variant:

- colors/background/bg-primary: primitive/color/white
- ...

3. **Component**

At the Component level, we are making use of the Semantic color properties, with the intention of exclusively referencing these Component-level properties within the XAML components. For example:

- Modal/background: semantic/colors/background/bg-primary

In the XAML, it's represented as follows:

Colors/Primitive.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
    <Color x:Key="DarkBlue800">#3D4B66</Color>
    <Color x:Key="White">#FFFFFF</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Colors/Themes/Dark.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Colors.Background.BgPrimary" Color="{DynamicResource DarkBlue800}"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Colors/Themes/Light.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Colors.Background.BgPrimary" Color="{DynamicResource White}"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Colors/Components.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Modal.Background" Color="{DynamicResource Colors.Background.BgPrimary}"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In the App.xaml we registered all resources:

```
Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- Themes -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Colors/Primitive.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Colors/Themes/Light.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Colors/Components.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
/Application.Resources>
```

The problem is that SolidColorBrush cannot be created from another SolidColorBrush:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="FromSCB" Color="{DynamicResource SomeSolidColorBrush}"/>
```

If I try to use such SolidColorBrush the application throws following exception:

[image]

SolidColorBrush has only Color dependancy property and thats why it cannot be derived from another SolidColorBrush.

I also tried using a binding proxy (explained in [this article](https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/)) along with the SolidColorBrushToColorConverter. However, I ran into an issue - DynamicResource doesn't work with Binding. When using StaticResource, it works, but the problem is that when I switch the semantic level, the color doesn't update.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
                    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:WpfTest.Converters" 
                    xmlns:binding="clr-namespace:WpfTest.BindingProxy">
    <converters:SolidColorBrushToColor x:Key="SolidToColor"/>
    <binding:ColorBindingProxy x:Key="Proxy.Colors.Background.BgPrimary" Data="{DynamicResource Colors.Background.BgPrimary}" />
    <!--DynamicResource throws an exception-->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Modal.Background" Color="{Binding Source={DynamicResource Proxy.Colors.Background.BgPrimary}, Path=Data, Converter={StaticResource SolidToColor}}"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Any ides?

Comment: Try something like `<DynamicResource x:Key="FromSCB" ResourceKey="SomeSolidColorBrush"/>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it in the component level and reference semantic SolidColorBrush `<DynamicResource x:Key="Modal.Background" ResourceKey="Colors.Background.BgPrimary"/>`. Modal.Background is used as Window background. Unfortunatly, I am getting an exception "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''System.Windows.ResourceReferenceExpression' is not a valid value for property 'Background'.'"

Comment: When using `<DynamicResource x:Key="FromSCB" ResourceKey="SomeSolidColorBrush"/>` did you reference `FromSCB` with StaticResource or DynamicResource?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use converters?
You'll Bind `Color` properties of WPF elements to `string` NameOfColor at your `ViewModel` with `Converter`

Example

```
<UserControl.Resources>        
        <conv:StringToColorConverter x:Key="StringToColorConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
<Button Foreground="{Binding NameOfColor Converter={StaticResource StringToColorConverter}}">
```

Your Converter class will look like

```
public class StringToColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value.ToString() == "Green")
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.SeaGreen);
            }
            else if (value.ToString() == "DarkGreen")
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkSeaGreen);
            }
            else if (value.ToString() == "Red")
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));
            }
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (string)value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The main goal is to preserve 3 levels of color definitions as described in my question. How would you achieve it with this solution?

Comment: Add converter to this using BindingProxy ‘<SolidColorBrush x:Key="FromSCB" Color="{DynamicResource SomeSolidColorBrush}"/>’